# Trouble positioning my header in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, header, position, sticky

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh2T2.png)I’ve run into a problem with placing my header and navigation where I want it while using Internet Explorer. It works fine with other browsers, but not IE. I think the issue is with using the sticky positioning, but I don’t know how to make my header compatible with Internet Explorer. I’ve included the relevant code and a picture of how the header looks in IE. The navigation is supposed to be at the bottom of the picture of the mountains, not at the top left of the page.

```
header {
   position: absolute;
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   clear: both;
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   border-top: 2px solid black;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   background-color: #2E2D2D;
   z-index: 1;
}

nav {
   width: 800px;
   height: 70px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search shows that it's not supported in IE:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility
- https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

To replicate the effects of sticky, you're going to have to use js. You can write this yourself or look for a "sticky polyfill" that is already out there.

Alternatively, you *could* update your design so it doesn't require `position: sticky`.

Comment: I would like to keep the sticky position for browsers like Chrome and Firefox. Is there a way to provide an alternative position for Internet Explorer, while keeping sticky for the others?

Comment: There are traditional ways to do it like setting a class on the `<html>` tag using conditional html if statements and then using that additional class to provide different styling but there is also the `@supports` rule. You can read about it here: https://css-tricks.com/using-feature-detection-conditionals-and-groups-with-selectors/. Polyfills are also still an option if you want the styling consistent across all browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will look into it.

Comment: Following your advice, I found a polyfill called stickybits. But I don't understand how to install or use it. Here is the website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stickybits?activeTab=readme#installing-from-a-package-manager
If anyone can help me figure this out, it would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like Stickybits is a **library** to _replace_ `position: sticky`. Stickyfill is a **polyfill**: https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill - just add the js to the page and job done. A **polyfill** runs code to _replicate_ unsupported functionality when needed but, other than itself, should require no more changes. Hope that helps.

Comment: I followed your advice again adding the sticky class to my header:

<header class="sticky">

Then I included this JavaScript right before the closing body tag:

<script>
      var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.sticky');
      Stickyfill.add(elements);
    </script>

Finally, I added updated my css rules by including this and the class sticky to my css:

position: -webkit-sticky;



Unfortunately, it didn't affect the problem at all. Am I doing something wrong? By the way, thank you for helping me with this!

Comment: I think everything may be in a strange state with all the incremental changes. I'd remove what you've added and get your code back to how it was when you asked the question. From that clean sheet, add the js file from Stickyfill and then follow "What it does" and "What it doesn't do" in the documentation; I'd only expect you to update your css (although it may need to be into a new class). If you still can't get it to work then I'd need to see more code to know why, so if you could get your original 'clean state' into a jsfiddle then I can see for myself and let you know how I get it to work.

Comment: I finally figured it out! All I had to do was replace absolute with relative positioning in the following code, as well as use the pollyfill:
header.sticky {
    position: absolute;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #2E2D2D;
    z-index: 1;
}
Thank you again!

Comment: Wonderful, I'm glad I could help. I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer if you feel it answered your question. All the best.